# How to Stop KDE Migration Agent Popping Up at Login? (Kubuntu)

Tags: kubuntu, login

Every time I reboot or login before the login animation progress bar has even finished KDE Migration Agent pops up asking for my password.
How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this thread: https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/510917-New-leap-final-installation-on-laptop-On-each-login-get-twice-Kwalletmigration-agent-asking-for-pa

There you'll find an explanation on how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem.
The solution was to go to kwallet and make a new wallet with new password

Comment: I did this and the migration popup stopped. The old passwords were never imported anywhere though. Luckily, I had long ago stopped using KWallet for anything but WIFI passwords. KeepassX is much more reliable, and it did a similar migration smoothly and without issues.